# postgres append text to a text cell

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres db with **text** records in a row named "filmid".
looks like this:

```
select * from films order by filmid;

ID  filmid
1   3
2   23
3   241
```

now what I want to do for testing is first to change one cell value:

```
UPDATE films SET filmid = '0000' WHERE externalid = '23';
```

but that doesn't change anyting.

Later I want to append text ("0000") to all of the cell elements from the row filmid so that it looks like this:

```
ID  filmid
1   30000
2   230000
3   2410000
```

But I can't figure out how to do that

Comment: Why are you storing numbers in a `text` column? That's a bad idea to begin with

Comment: because for other stuff thats also used with alphabetical chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want string concatenation?

```
UPDATE films SET filmid = filmid || '0000';
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that's it. Only one problem I found out with that: the stings have blank spaces attached. so your query does this: 3       0000 instead of 30000
how can I get rid of the blank spaces?

Comment: @temporalis: ok, so `SET filmid = trim(filmid) || '0000'`

Comment: how can I remove the 0000 from the prior query to redoo it with the new one?